# How to edit a list template in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have made a number of lists using custom list template in SharePoint 2010. I would like to add a column to each of these lists. Microsoft offers the following [super helpful instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-list-templates-HA010099156.aspx)

> **Edit the list template properties**
>
> On the Site Actions menu , click Site Settings.
>
> NOTE   On a site for which the Site Actions menu is customized, point
>   to Site Settings, and then click the settings that you want to view.
>
> 1. In the Galleries column, click List templates.
>
> NOTE   This option
>   appears only to users who have the Manage Lists permission. Site
>   owners have this permission by default.
>
> The List Template Gallery page appears.
>
> 1. In the Edit column, click Edit Document Properties for the list
>      template that you want to edit.
> 2. Edit the information that you want to
>      change, and then click OK.

What they neglect to mention is that this gives you access to exactly 3 things

1. the template file ( eg: myTemplate.stp )
2. the template name
3. the template description

My question is, how do you ACTUALLY EDIT THE TEMPLATE? ie: change columns

I van crack open the file itself by downloading the .stp  renaming it to a .cab extracting the .xml and making changes there. But without some testing I have no idea what will happen if I try re-compressing that file and replacing an existing template with it.

Has anyone done this themselves? Does anyone know of an alternative method to add a column to a list template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a List using the template, make the edits, then create a new template from the List you just created.

If you need the template to carry the same name, you can deactivate and delete the original, then save the new template with the proper name.

Comment: That's "making a new template which happens to look like the old one". What happens to lists using that template if I then rename the new one to replace the old one? Do they get the new column and keep their old data?

Comment: No, you would have to edit them manually with this approach. Their data and structure would remain unchanged.

Comment: So the answer is, you can't edit a template, and even if you could it wouldn't matter. Thank you for your response, it's tough getting any SP information at all.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your problem. I also recommend using the msdn forums. It moves a bit slower than stack overflow, but I feel that SP question/s will be read by more people with SP expertise.

Answer (score 1):

In SP2003 I used to download the STP file, rename it to CAB, edit the inner XML manually, repackage with Makecab and upload the new STP file back to the template gallery.

However I must say that in SP2010 I can't seem to get what I want (a custom URL column calculated from other columns) without SP throwing fits, so I wish you luck.

Comment: Ha, good to know that it's a process that "could" work. I don't imagine the changes were retroactive though?

Comment: @Sinetheta - if by "retroactive" you mean that the template changes apply to lists that you have already previously created with the "same" template - no that doesn't work.  The modified template is uploaded as a new one.